# How do I remove a trailing % symbol from the json output of a REST API Call?

Tags: python-3.x, rest

I'm currently working with an API which for some reason, when you query with one specific parameter, returns the data with a trailing %, which when running json.dump(), is failing because of that symbol.

What's the easiest way to remove the trailing character please?

Comment: Can you just `.strip("%")` it out?